# how to write mockito test for action classes(struts2)

Tags: mockito

`

> Blockquote

How to write test class to test action classes using mockito?

Comment: You'll need to provide more specifics. In general you'd only mock your service classes if you're not testing the complete request cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using JUnit?  Think about having one test method for each requirement that your class has to meet, or each particular scenario of a requirement.  Once you've planned out what each test method will be, work out

- what you need to set up in each test method,
- what the actual call to your class will look like within the test method,
- what you need to verify at the end of the test method.

Use Mockito when any of your test methods are likely to use functionality *outside* of the class that you're actually trying to test.  Mocking is all about removing the behaviour of other classes (collaborator classes) from what happens during your test.  Once you've identified what these other classes are, and what behaviour you want from them, then you can start using Mockito.

But you really need to plan out your tests first.  Mockito is not a silver bullet that will test things for you.

I'm sorry, but I really can't give a more detailed answer than this, unless you would care to add some detail to your question.  Right now, your question is remarkably vague.